# ListView with small amount of items is not scrollable

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I have very common ListView (in a very common Windows Universal app), which is placed in a very common grid on a very common page.

```
<Grid Margin="12,24,12,0">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AccountsItemTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding AccountList}" /> 
</Grid>
```

The thing is: if i have 3-5 items (so they all fit on a screen), scroller is disabled. If i have more than a dozen, then scroller is enabled and everything's fine.

How can i force scroller to appear in a listview which is smaller than a screen size?

Comment: I don't follow. You say you have a scroller no matter how many elements are in the list, but it is sometimes disabled. When doesn't it appear?

Comment: @zmbq it doesn't appear when i have small amount of items, so all of them are fitting the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode to Enabled and it will always be possible to scroll vertically (pull up and down really) even if all the items fit on the screen and scrolling is not needed.

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AccountsItemTemplate}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AccountList}" />
```

Comment: Exactly! I tried start writing "ScrollViewer", but intellisence said it knows nothing about it. The rare case when copypasting saves a day :) PS: congrats with 6K points!